# Need to modify this export macro for text tab delimited output

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I found a script on here that will export each worksheet in a file to a .csv file, but I need to adjust it to export the sheets as text tab delimited files instead.  I tried to modify it, but it is just exporting as text with no delimiter.  Here is the original code:

```
Public Sub DoTheExport()
Dim FName As Variant
Dim Sep As String
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim csvPath As String


Sep = InputBox("Enter a single delimiter character (e.g., comma or semi-colon)", _
"Export To Text File")
'csvPath = InputBox("Enter the full path to export CSV files to: ")

csvPath = GetFolderName("Choose the folder to export CSV files to:")
If csvPath = "" Then
    MsgBox ("You didn't choose an export directory. Nothing will be exported.")
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
wsSheet.Activate
nFileNum = FreeFile
Open csvPath & "\" & _
  wsSheet.Name & ".csv" For Output As #nFileNum
ExportToTextFile CStr(nFileNum), Sep, False
Close nFileNum
Next wsSheet

End Sub
```

And here is how I have modified it:

```
Public Sub DoTheExport()
Dim FName As Variant
Dim Sep As String
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim nFileNum As Integer
Dim txtPath As String


'Sep = InputBox("Enter a single delimiter character (e.g., comma or semi-colon)", _
'"Export To Text File")
'csvPath = InputBox("Enter the full path to export CSV files to: ")

txtPath = GetFolderName("Choose the folder to export TXT files to:")
If txtPath = "" Then
    MsgBox ("You didn't choose an export directory. Nothing will be exported.")
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
wsSheet.Activate
nFileNum = FreeFile
Open txtPath & "\" & _
  wsSheet.Name & ".txt" For Output As #nFileNum
ExportToTextFile CStr(nFileNum), Sep, False
Close nFileNum
Next wsSheet

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you're not setting `Sep` to be anything whereas it looks as if it should be your delimiter. Use the following before your `For Each..` loop.

```
Sep = vbTab
```

Or

```
Sep = Chr(9)
```